# Cardinal fixed point exercise in Kunen

Tags: logic, set-theory

The following is an exercise in Kunen's set theory textbook (new edition):

[image: Kunen exercise I.11.8]

I think I can prove that $\aleph_{\delta_\omega} = \delta_\omega$, but I don't understand the following: once the fixed point $\delta_\omega$ is reached the iteration gets stuck, since $\delta_{\omega+1} = \aleph_{\delta_\omega} = \delta_\omega$, etc. If this is indeed correct then in particular $\delta_{\omega_1} = \delta_\omega$, but Kunen's comment after the exercise explicitly rules this out.

What goes wrong?

Comment: A typo, probably. Redefine the sequence at successor steps as the cardinal successor of the current version.