# On Kunen's Set Theory Exercise I.11.8

Tags: set-theory

The following exercise appears in Kunen's *Set Theory*, with the following remarks.

> **Exercise I.11.8** Applying transfinite recursion, define $\delta_\epsilon$ by:
>
> - $\delta_0=0$,
> - $\delta_{\epsilon+1}:=\aleph_{\delta_\epsilon}$,
> - $\delta_\eta:=\sup\{\delta_\epsilon:\epsilon<\eta\}$ when $\eta$ is a [nonzero] limit ordinal.
>
> Show that $\aleph_{\delta_\eta}=\delta_\eta$ for all [nonzero] limit $\eta$.
>
> It is consistent with $\sf ZFC$ to have the continuum $\mathfrak{c}$ be $\delta_{\omega_1}$; then $\mathfrak{c}=\aleph_\mathfrak{c}$ (see Corollary IV$.3.14$). One cannot have $\mathfrak{c}=\delta_\omega$ by König's Theorem I.13.12.

(For $\omega_1:=\aleph_1$).

However, using the result of the exercise, the class $\{\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega\text{ or }\delta_\alpha=\delta_\omega\}$ appears to be inductive on the ordinals, because

- if $\alpha$ is an ordinal in $A$, then either $\alpha+1<\omega\subseteq A$, or $\alpha\geq\omega$, thus $\delta_{\alpha+1}=\aleph_{\delta_\alpha}=\aleph_{\delta_\omega}=\delta_\omega$.
- if $\alpha$ is a limit and $\alpha\subseteq A$, then either $\alpha\leq\omega$, or $\delta_\alpha=\sup\{\delta_\epsilon:\epsilon\leq\omega\}=\delta_\omega$.

Thus, $\delta_\omega=\delta_{\omega_1}$. This seems to contradict the remark that the continuum could be $\delta_{\omega_1}$ but could not be $\delta_\omega$. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: I think there was already a question about this. Clearly, a problem. Replace the successor steps by adding a ${}^+$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496260/cardinal-fixed-point-exercise-in-kunen